# Track time stamp to check Option Group Checkbox (YES or NO)in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to track timestamp to store in one field when the user check as 'Yes' from Option group checkbox and same for another field as 'No'. Please help me with this.
Basically I want to track Yes checkbox timestamp and No checkbox timestamp in access form.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a little weird to have separate text boxes for yes and no, but I created another field for "TestTimeStamp" and then just update that value when the check box is updated.

```
Private Sub TestCheck_AfterUpdate()
    Forms!TestForm.TestTimestamp.Value = Now()
End Sub
```